# An example of a non rigid Banach algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

A  Banach  algebra $A$ is called  a  rigid  Banach algebra if  for  every injective  Banach algebra morphism $J:A\to A$ we  have  either $\overline{J(A)}$ is ismorphic to $A$ or it does not contain any  isometric copy of $A$.

What is  an example of  a non rigid Banach algebra?

This  concept is defined in the context of Banach spaces and one observe that $\ell^{\infty}$ is not a Rigid Banach space. So in this post we search for a Banach algebraic version. In this line please see the following note:

https://maco.lu.ac.ir/article-1-113-en.html

Comment: Can't you just consider the algebra structure on $\ell^\infty$ given by pointwise operations?

Comment: @Wojowu  it is a Banach  algebra  structure but what about injective  Banach algebra  morphisms?You possibly means that it is  non rigid as a  Banach algebra  too?

Comment: Well, every injective Banach algebra morphism is in particular an injective Banach space morphism. So you at least know it either doesn't contain a copy of $\ell^\infty$, or is isomorphic to it as a Banach space. I suppose it's not obvious that it is isomorphic as an algebra, but it at least sounds plausible to me.